# How can i bind ngModel value with options list of dropdown in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, dropdown

**Example:**

```
<p-dropdown name="senderId" [options]="senderIdList" [filter]="true" required 
    #senderIdDrpdwn="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedSenderId"></p-dropdown>
```

In senderIdList = having a list of all the values.
In selectedSenderId =  having a value from senderIdList.

But the output is showing list only when I select on dropdown but I want onload value is (which is in ngModel) and then to click on dropdown shows all the list(senderIdList).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-twkgar?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
  selected: any;
  cities = {};

  countries = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Sri lanka"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "India"
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Japan"
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(
      "Changed Value is ",
      deviceValue,
      "name",
      this.countries[deviceValue].name
    );
    this.selected = this.countries[deviceValue - 1].name;
   }
```

.html

```
<select name="city" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries"  [value]="country.id" >{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>
{{selected}}
```